# Are individual auto-reactive 'lymphocytes' or auto-reactive 'clones' generated in the central lymphoid organs?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, autoimmune

[Clonal deletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonal_deletion) is a well-known mechanism of immune central tolerance. But individual *lymphocytes* or *lymphocyte clones* are subjected to apoptosis? If *clones*, then what is the reason to allow mitosis in auto-reactive cells? If *lymphocytes*, then why do we use the adjective? I mean are there several rounds of mitosis in a (potentially) harmful say B lymphocyte prior to negative selection step?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the definition of clone at this level. As clonal deletion is a central tolerance mechanism, of all the possible clones of B cells (a clone is a B cell with a particular arrangement of the BCR), those clones (not identical clones, but different clones each) that are self-reactive will undergo apoptosis. That means that self-reactive clones are deleted and they won't divide anymore.

Comment: so, 1 clone = 1 B cell, any reference?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).